# How can i parse the last 3 tweets instead of the last 1 with json

Tags: android, json, parsing, twitter

i got this code working and it to return the last tweet from my brother, i would like to it to return the last 3 tweets can somebody help me? im not really good in java or xml i just followed a few tutorials from mybringback, please ignore my bad English.

i think the problem is in the line: JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0); this makes it return the first tweet so how do i alter this so it returns the first 3? (0, 1 ,2) isn't allowed :(

```
package net.thinkbin;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class menu extends Activity {
TextView httpStuff;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;


final static String URL = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp1);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Read().execute("Title");

    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.TUTORIAL1"));
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.SHARE"));
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public JSONObject lastTweet(String username) 
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);

    System.out.println(url.toString());


    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);

        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);

        return last;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(menu.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}




public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    json = lastTweet("koen*****");
                    return json.getString("params[0]");
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        return null;                
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpStuff.setText(result);
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DilSe url and try this code.

```
public JSONArray lastTweet(String username) 
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
    url.append(username);

    System.out.println(url.toString());


    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200){
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        return new JSONArray(data);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(menu.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}




public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    JSONArray timeline = lastTweet("koen*****");
                    return timeline.getJSONObject(0).getString("params[0]")+" : "
                                     +timeline.getJSONObject(1).getString("params[0]")+" : "
                                     +timeline.getJSONObject(2).getString("params[0]");

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        return null;                
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpStuff.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: i  got it to work(something stupid on my side) thanks! only if i would like the tweets to be under each other what should i change ":" too?

Answer (score 2):

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=username&count=3

use this url instead of your url

Just a minor change in your url is append "&count=3"

Comment: this line of makes it only return the first tweet                   JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);

Comment: how can i alter this line so it return 0, 1, 2

Comment: because of the line JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0); it only returns the first tweet from the json page so how do i alter this line so it returns the first 3

Comment: Just silly answer use a loop to do so. i.e., for(int i=0;i<3;i++){your logic/code}